# Circular import error while organising __init__.py files

Tags: python, django, import

I am making a series of python files in to their own module.  As such I've put them in a directory and added an init file.

In order for me to be access them as follows

```
from module import subclass
```

rather than

```
from module.submodule import subclass
```

I am trying to import all the classes I want to expose in to the **init** file.  However since lots of the submodules refer to each other (its a Django project so all the classes are foreign key'd to one another) when I run the code I very quickly run in to circular imports.

Is there a correct way to organise an **init**.py file such that this is avoided?

For example:

```
  File "/Users/.../models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from Guests import Guest
  File "/Users/.../models/Guests.py", line 5, in <module>
from Logs import LogEntry
  File "/Users/..../models/Logs.py", line 6, in <module>
from Staff import Staff
  File "/Users/.../Staff.py", line 5, in <module>
from Properties... import Site
  File "/Users/./Properties.py", line 7, in <module>
from Guests import Guest
ImportError: cannot import name Guest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A depends on X and X depends on A probably they suppose to live within same unit, it's better to examine and split your circular dependency into same module then looking for workaround.

**Not recommended:** However if you cannot adjust structure of your packages you can move circular import into  function definition or follow that principle( i don't know your code ...)  .

If class A.py depends on B.py and B.py depends on A.py:

```
# B.py
class B:

  def __init__(self):
        import A 
        A.some_method()
```

**Update:** As pointed in comments that's Django foreign key variable cause circular imports to avoid that problem Remove the import of class and use the model name as a string instead.

```
item = models.ForeignKey('class_file.Item')
```

Comment: The problem is that there is a logging model which acts to log changes in all of the other Django model so that would tie everything together but then the code is O(3k) lines long which is a bit unmanageable.  Its not so much that they depend on one another directly - A calls B but B is foreign key'd to A.

Comment: I also cant 'hide' the imports in a function definition since the Django foreign keys are class variables.

Comment: use full comment, i've adjusted answer again.

Comment: Ah I did not know you could pass paths as strings to foreign keys, thanks!